# R data.table remove rows by grouping?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that includes a `displayDate` field and also many rows per user, each with a different displayDate. Each user joined the service and started logging data at a different point in time. For each user I want to find the first week's worth of data only, so I'd like to get rid of rows that are not within the first week for a given user. Here's what I'd like to do, but this produces an error:

```
early_data = dt[displayDate <= min(displayDate) + 7, , by=user]
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, displayDate <= min(displayDate) + 14, , by = user) : 
  'by' or 'keyby' is supplied but not j
```

Is there a way to conditionally select rows by grouping on another column? What's wrong with my syntax above?

Comment: You could also do: `dt[, .SD[displayDate <= min(displayDate) + 7], by=user]`

Comment: for the record, this use case is described as improvement in [data.table#1105](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1105)

Answer (score 3):

We may need to get the row index (`.I`) from the logical vector and use that to subset the rows.

```
 dt[dt[, .I[displayDate <= min(displayDate)+ 7], by =user]$V1]
```

---

One problem with the OP's code is that we are only using the `i` along with the `by` option and in between there are only commas (`, ,`) and no `j` is provided (as mentioned in the error)

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
dt <- data.table(displayDate = sample(seq(as.Date("2014-07-01"),
            length.out=20, by = "1 day")), user = rep(1:4, each=5))
```